# Stuck on getting total count and count of certain elements of an array

Tags: java, arrays

I'm trying to create two methods in the LineUp class, one method called totalMembers in which it would return the total number of members and another one called totalKinds doing the same thing but returning the number of different kinds of acts.

Here is the code for the Act class in which it creates a program for managing a musical festival (sort of)

```
public class Act {
    private int num_members;
    private String name;
    private String kind;
    private String stage;


    public Act(int num_members, String name, String kind, String stage) {
        this.num_members = num_members;
        this.name = name;
        this.kind = kind;
        this.stage = stage;
    }

    public Act(int num_members, String name, String kind) {
        this.num_members = num_members;
        this.name = name;
        this.kind = kind;
        stage = null;
    }

    public int getNum_members() {
        return num_members;
    }

    public void setNum_members(int num_members) {
        this.num_members = num_members;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getKind() {
        return kind;
    }

    public void setKind(String kind) {
        this.kind = kind;
    }

    public String getStage() {
        return stage;
    }

    public void setStage(String stage) {
        this.stage = stage;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return "(" + num_members + ", " + name + ", " + kind + ", " + stage + ")";
    }
}
```

The class LineUp represents these acts and here is the code for it thus far. I was thinking of using a for loop to get the number of members for each act however as it's not a 2D array it's much harder to do. For getting the different kinds of acts I have no clue. If anyone could put me in the right direction that would be great.

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class LineUp {
    private Act[] acts;
    private int number;
    private int memberSum;

    public LineUp() {
        acts = new Act[30];
        number = 0; 
        memberSum = 0;
    }

    public int numberOfActs() {
        return number;
    }

    public int totalMembers() {
        for(int i=0; i < acts.length; i++) {

        }
        return memberSum;
    }

    public int totalKinds() {

    }

    public void addAct(Act a) {
        if(number == 30)
            System.out.println("The festival is full!");
        else {
            acts[number] = a;
            number++;
        }
    }

    public String toString() {
        return acts + "";
    }

    public void Print() {
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(acts));
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by 2D array and why it's harder calling getNum_members inside the first loop (totalNembers). Not sure if Im missing anything.

Comment: As it's just an array, I don't know how I would access just the no. of members index of the array as it's technically an array within an array. Sorry if the wording is scrambled up, I'm a beginner to java.

Comment: How would I go about in calling getNum_members as I would have to create an object, no?

Comment: acts[i].getNum_members();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To properly model Acts you **must** use [actors](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/actors.html). No, just kidding, sorry for that one.

You have rather many different possibilities evaluating the content of your `act[]`. A brute, archaic version would go like this

```
    public int totalKinds() {
        List<String> unique = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < acts.length; i++) {
            if (!unique.contains(acts[i]))
                unique.add(acts[i].getKind());   
        }
        return unique.size();
    }
```

E.g. you could use enhanced for loops and exploit the fact, that a set has unique elements:

```
   public int totalKinds() {
        Set<String> unique = new HashSet<>();
        for (Act a: acts) {
            unique.add(a.getKind());
        }
        return unique.size();
    }
```

Certainly the most flexible and convenient way is to use the stream api, introduced with Java 8. It really pays off to [get acquainted](https://winterbe.com/posts/2014/07/31/java8-stream-tutorial-examples/) with it. Note that `count()` returns a `Long`, while you want `int`, so there's a conversion needed.

```
    public int totalKinds() {
        long count = Arrays.asList(acts).stream()
                .map(act -> act.getKind())
                .distinct()
                .count();
        return Math.toIntExact(count);
    }
```